# django url cache works when only page reload by f5

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Maybe It's duplicate of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799255/django-cache-only-gets-set-on-page-reload).

**My urls.py:**

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

app_name = 'alphabet'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<alp>a|b|c|d|e)/$', cache_page(60 * 15)(views.alp), name='alp'),
]
```

**my_template.html:**

```
<div class="non_seen" id="url_custom" data-custom="{% url 'alphabet:alp' alp='a' %}"></div>
```

**And my template file(from my_template.html) there's some js(jquery) code to go that url:**

```
$('#btn_custom').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = $('#url_custom').attr('data-custom');
}
```

While I monitor my redis-cli, there's redis monitor logs `cache get or set event` if I reload(refresh, click F5) page `127.0.0.1:8000/a` but when I click `#btn_custom`, there's no event like that.

**Question:** Why this happened and How to make it cache to every request(including click `#btn_custom` not only when click F5?

Comment: I don't know where your issue is, but the code you've posted wouldn't work at all - `{% url 'alphabet:alp' %}` should raise a `NoReverseMatch` error because you haven't supplied the `alp` argument used in the regex.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks, I edited.

Comment: Setting `location.href` for the same URL as the current page will not cause the browser to reload the page - so Django will not see a request at all.